# Android WebRTC customize remote and local view

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc, glsurfaceview, libjingle

I am implementing the webrtc in an Android project and I am based on this sample [in github](https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo).

This example uses the libjingle library. This is how the video render view is created:

```
        // Create video renderers.
        VideoRendererGui.setView((GLSurfaceView)videoView, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createPeerConnectionFactory();
            }
        });
        remoteRender = VideoRendererGui.create(
                REMOTE_X, REMOTE_Y,
                REMOTE_WIDTH, REMOTE_HEIGHT, scalingType, false);
        localRender = VideoRendererGui.create(
                LOCAL_X_CONNECTING, LOCAL_Y_CONNECTING,
                LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTING, LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTING, scalingType, true);
```

My question is how can I manage to customize the `remoteRender` and `localRender`, so that I can change it `position` in the `GLSurfaceView` and its width and height

**EDIT:**

I have made a listener and I have tried this:

```
    @Override
    public void onWidthHeightChange(int width, int height) {
        VideoRendererGui.update(remoteRender,
                REMOTE_X-width, REMOTE_X-height,
                REMOTE_WIDTH-width, REMOTE_HEIGHT-height, scalingType, false);
        if (iceConnected) {
            VideoRendererGui.update(localRender,
                    LOCAL_X_CONNECTED, LOCAL_Y_CONNECTED,
                    LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTED, LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTED,
                    ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT, true);
        } else {
            VideoRendererGui.update(localRender,
                    LOCAL_X_CONNECTING, LOCAL_Y_CONNECTING,
                    LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTING, LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTING, scalingType, true);
        }
    }
```

When I give value 150 for both width and height it gives me this error:

```
08-21 14:34:01.621    7636-7636/org.appspot.apprtc E/AppRTCDemoActivity﹕ Fatal error: glUseProgram: GLES20 error: 1281
    java.lang.RuntimeException: glUseProgram: GLES20 error: 1281
            at org.webrtc.GlUtil.checkNoGLES2Error(GlUtil.java:48)
            at org.webrtc.GlShader.useProgram(GlShader.java:123)
            at org.webrtc.GlRectDrawer.drawOes(GlRectDrawer.java:132)
            at org.webrtc.VideoRendererGui$YuvImageRenderer.draw(VideoRendererGui.java:371)
            at org.webrtc.VideoRendererGui$YuvImageRenderer.access$800(VideoRendererGui.java:131)
            at org.webrtc.VideoRendererGui.onDrawFrame(VideoRendererGui.java:722)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

**EDIT 2 with the solution:**

When I was looking at `mattm` answer I understood that he was right.

While I was searching for my exception I found that it was an exception thrown from `libjingle` library. I found this piece of code here [VideoRendererGui.java](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk/app/webrtc/java/android/org/webrtc/VideoRendererGui.java?r=6360) at line 368, 347 I found the solution for my questions.

When adding the view height and width it has to be inside these ranges based on this code:

```
  /**
   * Creates VideoRenderer.Callbacks with top left corner at (x, y) and
   * resolution (width, height). All parameters are in percentage of
   * screen resolution.
   */
  public static YuvImageRenderer create(
      int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    // Check display region parameters.
    if (x < 0 || x > 100 || y < 0 || y > 100 ||
        width < 0 || width > 100 || height < 0 || height > 100 ||
        x + width > 100 || y + height > 100) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect window parameters.");
    }
```

So for as long as I follow these rules calling the method `VideoRendererGui.update(...` will work perfectly

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as changing the fields

- the coordinates:
  `REMOTE_X`, `REMOTE_Y`, or `LOCAL_X_CONNECTING`, `LOCAL_Y_CONNECTING`,
- or the dimensions:
  `REMOTE_WIDTH`, `REMOTE_HEIGHT` or `LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTING`, `LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTING`

If you want to change the rendering once the objects have been created, call `VideoRendererGui.update(remoteRender, ...)`.

Comment: I have tried that but It didnt work, and sometimes it crashed, I will try again and give you feedback. Thanks

Comment: I have found the reason why it crashed :) Thanks

Comment: @Ultimo_m I got the same issue what was the reason ?

Comment: @richashah you are giving values which are not accepted, check my answer above in the question, or check the method you call documentation. Try different values...

Comment: how to convert  VideoRendererGui.setView(binding.remoteStreamView) to surfaceview render ?